# Realm starts a new database every time the app runs

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

In RealmSwift 1.2 I noticed that the simulator would persist data between runs.  However, in RealmSwift2.0 I am not experiencing that?  Is it supposed to persist data between runs and I possibly messed something up or?

I believe I am use a standard method of saving objects:

```
try! realm.write{
    self.realm.add(self.theObject)
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code where you use Realm to persist Objects? Do you do any custom setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to persist data between runs, even in the simulator. Are you using the defaultRealm in an unmodified configuration? This behaviour would be only expected if you setup the Realm as inMemory, which is recommended in the docs for tests. So make sure that you don't have accidentally added test setup files to your app target.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same problem.  I have looked into the three targets of my app.  APPNAME, APPNAMETests, and APPNAMEUITests.  Maybe I am looking in the wrong places or not for the right thing.  What exactly should I be looking for?!  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have set anywhere an `inMemoryIdentifier`?

Comment: The only occurrences of "inMemoryIdentifier" occur in Realm.swift (pods), RealmConfiguration.swift (pods), RLMRealm.mm (pods), RLMRealmConfiguration.h (pods), and RLMRealmConfiguration.mm (pods).  Should I be initializing it?  Is there a solution via setting the location for realm to save to?  Thank you

Comment: Do you think it could have anything to do with including UITests but not actually doing anything with them?

Comment: Turned out I was removing the NSFileManager path for Realm.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, glad that you found that! Thanks for reporting back. :)